# Android Global SQLite Database Access

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to make my SQLite database globally accessible throughout my Android application using a singleton pattern:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "foo";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static MySQLiteOpenHelper instance;

    private MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static MySQLiteOpenHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static MySQLiteOpenHelper getInstance() throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        return instance;
    }

...
```

The idea here is that the first call is to `getInstance(Context context)` passing in the Application object. Thereafter I can just use `getInstance()` where I can't get a handle on a `Context` object.

However, I come unstuck when I make the initial `MySQLiteOpenHelper.getInstance(getApplication())` call:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:204)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
```

Can anyone shed any light on what is happening here or suggest a better technique for achieving my goal?

Cheers!

Comment: Just creating the `SQLiteOpenHelper` doesn't cause this. Post your helper `onCreate()` code, you probably have a `getWritableDatabase()` there.

Comment: Gah! I thought I wasn't committing any crimes in the `onCreate()` method, but I am indeed doing something naughty in there! I'll crawl back under my rock...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is just fine.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively
```

This is caused when you call e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` recursively.

One common cause for it is to call `getWritableDatabase()` in database helper `onCreate()`. The `onCreate()` gets invoked when `getWritableDatabase()` is called and the database does not exist. Calling `getWritableDatabase()` again is an error. You should use the writable `SQLiteDatabase` passed to `onCreate()` as an argument instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQLiteOpenHelper should works fine.

That class is not the problem.